# SL(n,Z) is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove, that $ SL_n(Z) $ is finitely generated.

I know, that

> Matrix in $ SL_2(Z) $ is generated by transvections $ \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & a\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\  b & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
>
> Matrix in $ SL_n(Z) $ is generated by transvections  $ E + a*E_{ij} $, где 
>   $ a = \pm1 $
>
> Matrix can be reduced to diagonal form $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & ... & ...\\  ... & 1 & ... \\ ... & ... & 1 \end{pmatrix} $

But I have a problem. In a ring Z I have no operation: multiplication $ * $, summation $ + $. But I have got operation $ gcd $ in this ring. So how can I translate matrix to diagonal form, if I don't have operation, which needed in Gauss method.

What should I do in this step?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is exactly, but it might help to think about the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: But for what do I should use Euclidean algorithm? For 2 vector in $ SL_{2}(Z) $?

Comment: For details, this answer maybe helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234631/about-the-special-linear-group-sln-mathbbz

Comment: A solution for the title question is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2943037/prove-that-sln-z-is-generated-by-n2-n-elements).