# Prove that $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $(n^2-n)$ elements.

Tags: group-theory, determinant, linear-groups

Statement : Prove that $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $(n^2-n)$ elements.

The determinant is a n linear function of the rows of the matrix. Given any matrix, if the determinant is nonzero, say $det(x_1, x_2, ...x_n) = \alpha$ then by simply scaling the last row of the matrix (i.e n elements) we can get , $det(x_1,x_2,...,\frac{x_n}{\alpha}) = 1$.

Am I correct? Please give some hint how to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, $SL(3,\Bbb Z)$ is generated by the matrices
$$\pmatrix{1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1},\quad
\pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1},\quad
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1},\quad
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1},\quad
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&0&1},\quad
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&1}.
$$

Can you prove this? And can you extend this to any $n$?

Comment: These are the elements with determinant 1, for creating any general matrix in $SL(3,Z)$, first we scale up the diagonal elements as required, and then, fix the $(i,j)$ th place with scaling by using the generator matrix with $a_{i,j}$ in it's $(i,j)$th place. This same thing can be done with $n*n$ matrices, by considering $(n^2-n)$ matrices with 1 at $(i,j)$th place, $1 \leq i,j \leq n$.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice and elementary article that $SL_n(\Bbb{Z})$ can even be generated by $2$ elements for all $n\ge 2$: [A pair of generators for the unimodular group](https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CMB-1962-024-x). For a discusssion on the minimal number of generators of $SL_n(\Bbb{Z})$ and $GL_n(\Bbb{Z})$ see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181366/minimal-number-of-generators-for-gln-mathbbz).

Comment: By the way there's an immediate argument (once one has elementary generation by the $e_{ij}(1)$) to have 3 generators: one first choose two permutation matrices generating the group of permutation matrices, and $e_{12}(1)$. The refinement to get 2 generators is a bit harder.

Comment: Can the same generators of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$  also generate $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ ?

Comment: @null, In the case that $n=1$, $\operatorname{GL}(n,\Bbb{C}) = \Bbb{C}^{\times}$, the multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers. Is $\Bbb{C}^{\times}$ finitely generated?

Comment: Oh, right! $n\geq 2$. But then for $n=2$, will not identity and matrix for $i$ (interchanging rows of identity) suffice? For $n=3$ on-wards, I don't intuitively see which matrices should suffice as generators. I am just guessing all of $s_1,s_2,s_3$ (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/181366/945380) ) are required, $s_2$ for generating $i$.

Comment: @null No, have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654172/general-linear-group-gl-nr-not-finitely-generated).